# WEBRTC problematics with firewall rules

Tags: javascript, udp, video-streaming, webrtc, simple-peer

I developed a webrtc platform for my company using SimplePeer JS library and PHP for the server-side. It's working like a charm with STUN and TURN servers (NODE JS) in most of the cases.

My problem appears when I have some big clients with complicated networks like firewall closed in outbound traffic because they can't open (or don't want for security policy) an UDP port range for all IP addresses ( because she is every time different as you know)

My question is, I think I need to use a relay server for stream media and not use a classical peer to peer solution. So what technology can I use for this?

Comment: Use a WebRTC TURN server configured for TCP.

Comment: yes thank you for your response, i already had a TURN server, but i figured out it didn't worked well. So i created a new one with COTURN and it's working perfectly !